# How to generate GUID automatically in Suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

How to generate GUID automatically in my suitelet(which is used for encryption & decryption). Currently i am calling another suitelet manually by opening the link , which has a form to generate GUID and then i manually harcoded that value in my current suitelet. I want to automate the process. Please advice .